# TSQL : conditional query issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, conditional-statements

I need to create a flag to identify all `Room_IDs` where the following is met:

- a "Qc-" `Status` is present within one `Hotel_ID`.
- the "Qc-" `Status`has a corresponding non "Qc-" `Status` (e.g.
  'qc-occupied' & 'occupied').
- the "Qc-" `Status` has to have a to have a smaller `Room_ID` than the
  non "Qc-" `Status`. (e.g. `Status` = 'qc-occupied' has a `Room_ID`=1 and `Status` = 'occupied' has a `Room_ID`= 5)

This is a simplified table (tableX) I am using as an example:

```
 **Hotel_ID  Room_Id     Status**
      1         1        vacant          
      1         2        qc-occupied  
      1         3        vacant          
      2         1        occupied       
      2         2        qc-vacant       
      2         3        vacant          
      3         1        qc-vacant       
      4         1        vacant         
      4         2        occupied        
      4         3        qc-vacant
      5         1        vacant
```

I need the following as a result:

```
 **Hotel_ID  Room_Id     Status         flag**
      1         1        vacant          0
      1         2        qc-occupied     0
      1         3        vacant          0 
      2         1        occupied        0
      2         2        qc-vacant       1
      2         3        vacant          1
      3         1        qc-vacant       0
      4         1        vacant          0
      4         2        occupied        0
      4         3        qc-vacant       0
      5         1        vacant          0
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: What have you tried and what problems did you encounter? "I need" doesn't show a lot of research and work.

Comment: I am sorry if that seemed impolite, I am completely stuck.. I cannot see a way to make it work. 
I have created a flag to aggregate a status with its QC counterpart.
flag 1 = CASE WHEN [status] = 'qc-occupied' or 'occupied' THEN 'occupied'
          WHEN [status] = 'qc-vacant' or 'vacant' THEN 'vacant' END,
flag 2 = CASE WHEN [status] like 'qc -%' then 'QC Order' ELSE 'None QC Order' END,
rn = ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by Hotel_ID order by Room_Id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a literal translation of the requirements into rather inelegant code. It can certainly be improved, e.g. by removing your first requirement ("qc-" present.) since it is implicit in the other two requirements. The second requirement is implicit in the third, allowing another improvement.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @TableX as Table ( Hotel_Id Int, Room_Id Int, Stat VarChar(16) );
insert into @TableX ( Hotel_Id, Room_Id, Stat ) values
  ( 1, 1, 'vacant' ), ( 1, 2, 'qc-occupied' ), ( 1, 3, 'vacant' ), 
  ( 2, 1, 'occupied' ), ( 2, 2, 'qc-vacant' ), ( 2, 3, 'vacant' ), 
  ( 3, 1, 'qc-vacant' ),
  ( 4, 1, 'vacant' ), ( 4, 2, 'occupied' ), ( 4, 3, 'qc-vacant' ), 
  ( 5, 1, 'vacant' );
select * from @TableX;

-- Literal translation of requirements.
declare @False as Bit = 0, @True as Bit = 1;
select Hotel_Id, Room_Id, Stat,
  QC_In_Hotel, QC_And_NonQC_In_Hotel, QC_Precedes_NonQC_In_Hotel,
  case when QC_In_Hotel = @True and QC_And_NonQC_In_Hotel = @True and
    QC_Precedes_NonQC_In_Hotel = @True then @True else @False end as Flag
  from (
    select Hotel_Id, Room_Id, Stat,
      -- Req: a "Qc-" Status is present within one Hotel_ID.
      case when exists ( select 42 from @TableX as I
        where I.Hotel_Id = O.Hotel_Id and I.Stat like 'qc-%' )
        then @True else @False end as QC_In_Hotel,
      -- Req: the "Qc-" Status has a corresponding non "Qc-" Status (e.g. 'qc-occupied' & 'occupied').
      case when exists ( select 42 from @TableX as I
        where I.Hotel_Id = O.Hotel_Id and
          ( ( I.Stat like 'qc-' + O.Stat ) or ( O.Stat like 'qc-' + I.Stat ) ) )
        then @True else @False end as QC_And_NonQC_In_Hotel,
      -- Req: the "Qc-" Status has to have a to have a smaller Room_ID than the non "Qc-" Status.
      case when exists ( select 42 from @TableX as I
        where I.Hotel_Id = O.Hotel_Id and
          ( ( I.Room_Id < O.Room_Id and I.Stat like 'qc-' + O.Stat ) or
            ( O.Room_Id < I.Room_Id and O.Stat like 'qc-' + I.Stat ) ) )
        then @True else @False end as QC_Precedes_NonQC_In_Hotel
      from @TableX as O ) as PH
  order by Hotel_Id, Room_Id;
```

Comment: Thank you @HABO this worked perfectly, I understand what you did.